# First line of file being skipped. Python

Tags: python

Below is a simple search. It works, except for the fact that `iterator` is skipping the first line of the file. Inside `iterator` The first `print` statement has the correct word, but the second `print` statement (after the `for` loop) has the second line of text, not the first.

What about this `for` loops behavior am I missing?

```
"""Searches for the query inside a file
"""
def lines(the_file, query):
    lines = open(the_file)
    line(lines, query)

def line(lines, query):
    line = lines.readline()
    iterator(line, lines, word, query)

def word(line, query):
    word = line.strip()
    conditional(query, word)

def iterator(this, that, function, query):
    print this
    for this in that:
        print this
        function(this, query)

def conditional(this, that):
    if this in that:
        output(that, True)
    else:
        None

def output(query, result):
    print query

def search(the_file, query):
    lines(the_file, query)

search('c:/py/myfile.txt', 'a')
```

Comment: You should avoid mixing `.readline()` and using the file as an iterator. The latter uses a read-ahead buffer that will mess up using `.readline()` until you issue a `.seek()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is here:

```
def line(lines, query):
    line = lines.readline()
    iterator(line, lines, word, query)
```

This line: `line = lines.readline()` is reading one line off the file before you start your iteration. Then in your `for` loop you're actually overwriting the `this` variable, it's not pointing to your original `line` anymore.

Comment: overwriting/redefining `this` is not nice but it's not the source of the problem

Comment: I think the OP was expecting that because they passed `line` as the `this` argument, the for loop would become `for line in file`, that's what I was trying to explain.

Comment: Thanks all. Fixed the issue. I removed the `line` function and feed `lines` directly to `iterator`. Also, more complexity was reduced because iterator takes one less argument :-D

Answer (score 1):

Variable `lines` is a file object and when you made a `readline()` you moved a pointer to a second line.